# Inject Spring beans into RestEasy

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, resteasy, inject

Is it possible to inject Spring beans into an RestEasy @Path class? I managed to do it with Jersey, with @InjectParam annotation, but for some other reasons, I need to switch to RestEasy, and I can't seem to find a way to do it (tried good ol' javax.inject.Inject, but nothing).

EDIT

This solution works:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-spring-integration-example/

but it's not injection.. I'd still prefer something a little more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply annotate your RestEasy class with Spring's @Component and then inject your beans using Spring's @Autowired.  Don't forget to include the annotation-config and component-scan elements in your spring configuration.

Comment: Tried with 3.0.4.Final, following ResteasyDoc it simply does not work. Using **SpringBeanAutowiringSupport** was the only way I could make it work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a working example that integrates RestEasy with Spring just try [spring-resteasy](https://github.com/exacode/spring-resteasy).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@Configurable` annotation to make a normal class (created by `new`) a spring Bean.
Then you can use the normal Spring annotation to inject everything in that class/instance like in a "normal" Spring Bean.

But that requires AspectJ!

@See [Spring Reference Chapter 7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Peter's answer but there is another way to do it: you make all your exposition beans (RESTEasy or JAX-WS, which are not Spring components) extending the `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`.

That way you can easily inject your Spring Services by @Autowired annotation in these classes.